# Change default username that appears in the terminal

Tags: 13.04, users, username

I want to change `something@something-pcname:~$` to `somethingElse@somethingElse-pcname:~$`. I

have already tried changing the user name from `something` to `somethingElse` but the terminal still displays `something@something`

Comment: Have you change on this "/etc/hostname" and this "/etc/hosts" ?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add a new user of name something

```
sudo adduser something
```

then switch to that account

```
su something
```

Open the `/etc/hostname` file in your favourite text editor, for example

```
sudo vim /etc/hostname
```

and edit the computer name to somethingElse-pcname
Done!

Comment: I don't see how creating a new user does what OP wants

Answer (score 2):

You can change the global variable PS1

```
PS1='somethingElse'
```

To make it persistent add the above line to the end of your ~/.bashrc and reload it with

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

the standard (in your ~/.bashrc) is something like

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

so you can play around with this.

have a look at this site for some useful variables in the bash prompt ([here](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-prompt-basics))